# BizTalk ESB tool kit 2.0 Material pdf

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.0

Previously I followed the [(MCTS): Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 (70-595) Certification Guide book](http://www.packtpub.com/mcts-microsoft-biztalk-server-2010-certification-guide/book) to get certification on BTS server 2010, this book helped me a lot to understand the patterns and different methods of BTS usage.

This time, In the same way, I would like to pass certification on BTS-ESB tool kit 2.0.

Please could any one suggest which book will give more on knowledge on BTS-ESB tool kit 2.0 basics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.1 learning website to learn something about BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.1. There have a lot of ESB Toolkit resources.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699598(v=BTS.70).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd876606.aspx